# Set focus on a control when Window is loaded with WinUI 3

Tags: c#, winui-3

I want to set focus to a textbox user control when the window is loaded.

I've tried putting `txtLogin.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);` in the constructor

I've also tried doing something like

```
    void MainWindow_Activated(object sender, WindowActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
      txtLogin.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
    }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `Loaded` event:

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.txtLogin.Loaded += (s, e) =>
    {
        this.txtLogin.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always place the text box you want to be focused on loading to be the first  in your xaml code.

For example, below the "ID" box would have focus although it is on my second column.

```
        <TextBox Header="ID"
             Text="{x:Bind EmployeeModel.Number, Mode=TwoWay}"
             Grid.Column="2"/>
        <TextBox Header="Name"
             Text="{x:Bind EmployeeModel.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```